# Staging redirecting to live site (under construction page)

Tags: wp-redirect, staging

I created a staging environment from my customers live wordpress website. now when I try to access it without being logged in as an admin, it redirects to the live "under construction" live site. Only on desktop. On mobile we can access it.

I've been working this way for a long time and it is the first time I encounter this problem. I am using ELementor Pro builder and Jupiter X theme.

I turned off Simple SSL plugin keeping the https active. Didn't work. I also double checked that I didn't have Seedprod's coming soon plugin installed.

Any idea how to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: you either have a caching issue or you didn't change the home_url and site_url in your staging site settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a caching issue as mobile is the same domain. Try a different browser or if you use Chrome.

Open Inspection Tool > Network Tab > then check Disable Cache

[image]

Then do a hard refresh. If you aren't sure how. Click and hold on the refresh icon with the inspection tool open.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the good info, the cache seems to have been the problem!